# Can't use NVM from root (or sudo)

Tags: node.js, nvm

I've noticed that my application uses different version of NodeJS when running from `sudo`.

```
$ node -v
v0.10.23
$ sudo node -v
v0.11.8-pre
```

This **v0.11.8-pre** caused me some problems, so I definitely don't want to use it, but I can't change it for root.

```
$ sudo nvm use v0.10.23
sudo: nvm: command not found
```

I've tried to install nvm from root user, but got error "NVM already installed", but still nvm not found when running from `sudo`. What is my problem?

Comment: Try `sudo -s` _then_ install `nvm`.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Sorry, but I wrote that I've tried to install it from root

Comment: try to delete /root/.nvm/ and reinstall nvm from scratch

Comment: there is no /root/.nvm. I've installed nvm from sudo and it was installed into regular user homedir

Comment: This solves all my problem as you had https://github.com/xtuple/nvm

Comment: If you are going to use nvm with sudo, then you've missed the nvm's primary purpose. 'nvm' is all about: "each user can install multiple node versions and separate node packages for each installed node version".

Answer (score 334):

My solution is to create symbolic links from the versions of `node` and `npm` I'm using to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node"
sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/npm" "/usr/local/bin/npm"
sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/npx" "/usr/local/bin/npx"
```

This makes `npm`, `npx` and `node` available to all users.

Comment: Great solution. just add " at the end of second line...(I could not edit this myself for some reason)

Comment: Great, this is by far the best solution. This way , root will always use the same npm / node version you are using on the nvm user, thanks!

Comment: Great solution, but if you change the version of node you're using, you'll have to re-run the above commands.

Comment: I use `npx` quite often. So I added it as well: `sudo ln -s "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/npx" "/usr/local/bin/npx"`

Comment: @SimpleJ how would you do the same for `babel-node`

Comment: @user566245 I think the comment above yours should work for `babel-node` as well. It's just a matter of creating a symbolic link from the binary you're trying to use as `sudo` to a directory in the sudo user's PATH.

Comment: I used this, but replaced the path with the which command, ex.

>sudo ln -s `which npm` /usr/local/bin


>sudo ln -s `which node` /usr/local/bin

Comment: I was having trouble with NVM on Windows with WSL2 and this solution worked.

Comment: In my case, it didn't work until I added the symlink in the `/usr/bin/` directory instead of `/user/loca/bin/`

Comment: This is the answer to all of the endless questions about sudo and npm. Should be the top answer on Stack Overflow on the topic

Comment: This was helpful for most of my node issues but wanted to share that I still had issues with this solution on a Raspberry Pi when trying to run PM2 commands as root with the symlinked node and npm solution... Not sure if anyone also ran into this but I ended up just installing the latest Node version manually in root without NVM.

Comment: Does not help. Installed global packages are not available ( installation is done under sudo )

Comment: This helped me - Here was my situation: I logged in as a user who is in the root group, installed nvm, the version of node I needed and tried to `sudo node` a file, but it gave me `sudo: node: command not found`.  I did the above and it works like a charm now.  I did NOT install a global version of node anywhere.  It all resides in the user's nvm folder

Comment: When running the command posted by thomas sudo ln -s ```"$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/npx" "/usr/local/bin/npx"``` it returns the error:

```ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/npx': File exists```

Answer (score 267):

The below list of commands (source: [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps#-installing-nodejs-on-a-vps)) seems to fix the problem

## WARNING!!!! In some circumstances, these commands can break your system! Make sure you know what do these command do!!! [related](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108162/how-to-solve-this-error-sudo-usr-local-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-ha)

```bash
n=$(which node); \
n=${n%/bin/node}; \
chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; \
sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

The above command is a bit complicated, but all it's doing is copying whatever version of node you have active via nvm into the `/usr/local/` directory (where user installed global files should live on a linux VPS) and setting the permissions so that all users can access them.

Comment: Awesome! Last night I ruined my entire RasPi 3 system by desperately changing permissions for npm all over the place, today I spent 3h looking for the best solution to install node/npm globally without the need of sudo for each npm call. Your solution went well with this post https://www.losant.com/blog/how-to-install-nodejs-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: This sounds like a great option, but I keep getting these errors : `chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink ‘/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v7.1.0/bin/node-debug’

chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink ‘/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v7.1.0/bin/node-inspector’`

Comment: Thanks it works! why do they have to make things so complicated?!

Comment: @RLaaa because it's node. By the way it works, but use with caution, in your user console, not in your root console, and you SHOULD test it be echoing $n before copying in your usr/local/bin

Comment: Helped me alot, I'm using Linode VPS and I had a problem with nvm installed as root, but not accessible for another users. This solves it, thanks.

Comment: I believe this will copy the current version of node that nvm has, but I guess your system version will then be stuck at whatever version nvm is currently running when you runt his command. Just a heads up. Also could be better to use a symlink here instead of duplicating files.

Comment: this solution although appears to work, but defeats the purpose of NVM. with nvm we are changing what directory is in the part depending on which node version you have loaded. this command will just copy whatever directory was loaded at that time

Comment: ` sudo su`
`sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`
oh come on

Comment: After running this got the `sudo: /usr/local/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set` as well.  **LOOKS LIKE IT WILL REQUIRE A SERVER REBUILD!**

Comment: PLEASE add a test for empty $n. Just bricked my entire system by not checking that first :P

Answer (score 29):

The fundamental reason is because `nvm` is not a real program. It's a bash function that gets loaded in the user's `.profile`, `.bashrc`, or ... So `sudo` doesn't automatically pick it up from the $PATH like most other programs.

An alternative node version manager is `n`: https://github.com/tj/n . That is a real program, so `sudo` will pick it up via the $PATH without any hacks (as long as `sudo` has `/usr/local/bin` in its $PATH).

```
sudo npm install -g n  # install 'n' globally
which n                # should be /usr/local/bin/n

sudo n lts             # need sudo to switch node versions
node --version         # v6.10.0
sudo node --version    # v6.10.0
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks "nvm is not a problem, but a bash function" :)

Comment: Haha, just realized about my misspelling "problem" instead of "program" ;).

Comment: For mw `which npm` gives `/home/asc/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/npm` and doing `sudo npm install -g n` followed by `which n` gives `/home/asc/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/n`.

Answer (score 19):

Your problem is, that `nvm` is not in the path when you use `sudo`.

So type

```
$ which nvm
```

and the result will be something like

```
/home/abc/mynvm/nvm
```

Try again now with `sudo`:

```
sudo /home/abc/mynvm/nvm use v0.10.23
```

I assume you then run into the issue that the root user can't find the 0.10.13-version, but lets see the next error message...

Comment: `which nvm` outputs nothing

Comment: try as root `which nvm` and then go with `sudo <pathtonvm>/nvm use v0.10.23`. What happens now? (By the way - this is not a node or any programming language issue. That is something with your linux machine configuration...)

Comment: it outputs nothing for root as well

Comment: Hmmm... "locate nvm"? How did you produce this 'already installed' message?

Comment: Look at the source of this script: It says `NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"; ... if [ -d "$NVM_DIR" ]; then
  echo "=> NVM is already installed in $NVM_DIR, trying to update"`. With `sudo` you use your local home dir and not root home dir. Install as real root user and it should work.

Comment: Problem is that I never log in as root. Why should I? If I need any root access I always use `sudo`. Yes, I can log in as root and install nvm, but in future I couldn't run `sudo nvm use v0.10.25`. So I couldn't use `sudo node` from user as well.

Comment: Then set the appropriate env variables by hand. Or do `sudo bash`. The issue you have is about wrongly set env variables due to different handling of `sudo` and `login`.

Comment: `which nvm` doesn't ever work, does it? `nvm` isn't an executable, it's a shell function. https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/540

Comment: I recently asked a similar question about `which nvm` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156104/what-is-the-equivalent-to-which-for-commands-that-dont-refer-to-scripts-or-ex
Use `type nvm` to reveal its definition. As Matt said, it's a shell function.

Comment: From [nvm documentation](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#verify-installation);
"Please note that which nvm will not work, since nvm is a sourced shell function, not an executable binary."
So use
```shell
command -v nvm
```

Comment: echo $NVM_DIR outputs where nvm resides for me it was /home/USER_NAME/.nvm

Comment: this does not work for me. "which nvm" output a very long shell function source code, not an executable file

Answer (score 19):

## According to [README](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md)

> When using nvm you do not need `sudo` to globally install a module with `npm -g`, so instead of doing `sudo npm install -g grunt`, do instead `npm install -g grunt`

## Need sudo npm?

In my case, I need to `sudo npm run start` which needs the access to some file requiring root access. According to [this issue](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/1935),

> You don't use `sudo`. You should instead chmod/chown the file so that the user that has nvm has access to the file;.

## In sum

The maintainer of nvm strongly believe we don't need to `sudo` :P

Comment: so, if I want to use a serial device, I should chmod my `/dev/ttyS0` as well then?

Comment: Not really true for some packages.

Answer (score 7):

I had your problem too. Finally I have worked around it. Here is my solution:

1. Uninstall nvm and nodejs. Here are some helpful links: [Uninstallation of nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/298). If you installed nodejs using apt-get, you can uninstall it with the command `apt-get purge nodejs`.
2. Install a global nvm. See this page : [nvm global](https://github.com/xtuple/nvm). As it says, "Standard nvm has known difficulties working in multi-user or rooted environments."

After restarting your terminal, you can run the command `sudo nvm ls`.

Comment: This branch is 12 commits ahead, 1123 commits behind creationix:master. taken straight from the xtuple repo for nvm

Answer (score 7):

```
$ sudo bash -ic "nvm use stable; npm -v"
Now using node v6.3.1 (npm v3.10.3)
3.10.3
```

Comment: this doesn't work if nvm isn't already on the root user's path, which is the issue.

Answer (score 6):

By extending @SimpleJ solution I have created a useful bash script that could be used to link all binaries from actual nvm bin dir to `/usr/local/bin`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

DIR=$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/*
DEST=/usr/local/bin

for filename in $DIR; do
    filename=$(basename $filename)
    DEST_FILE=$DEST/$filename
    echo "Copying $filename to $DEST_FILE"
    sudo ln -sf "$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin/$filename" "$DEST_FILE"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

I have tried the same on my machine where I have `nvm` as well and I have a slighlty different response:

```
$ sudo node --version                                                                                                                                                                    
sudo: node: command not found
```

My guess is that you have installed node 0.11 outside of nvm. (*Via package manager or even from source*)

Therefore, running node via sudo would pick up this standalone node instead.

Does that make sense or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've installed *node* and then *nvm*. But everything works OK for normal user and does not work for the root.

Comment: Oh alright. Then, I think that nvm is not meant to be runned as root. In fact I am pretty that running in user land is a wanted feature. However, this might help you: https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/5

Comment: This guy apparently made a special nvm that run in sudo mode: https://github.com/xtuple/nvm. Unfortunately only in sudo mode. I don't know if it's acceptable

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this will likely be to just hit the nvm.sh executable wherever it is.

```
sudo /home/ubuntu/.nvm/nvm.sh install node
```

This works fine for me (assuming that's the install path).

The full install procedure would look like

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="/home/ubuntu/.nvm"

[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

And then you can run the command above to hit the newly installed nvm.sh

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to just install latest node-js from NVM API, without going for additional packages-purged versions. So I was looking to SUDO nvm install-latest-npm. Mb this will work for you - it definetely worked for me without installing/removing any apts. (Obviously change YOUR_USER_DIRECTORY for something suitable on ur system)

```
sudo /home/YOUR_USER_DIRECTORY/.nvm/nvm.sh | nvm install-latest-npm
```

Answer (score 0):

I had installed `nvm` and `node` as an unprivileged user.

To use these as sudo, I added this to the superuser's `.bashrc` file:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME/.bashrc'
/root/.bashrc
```

Contents to add to `/root/.bashrc` (replace `<your-user>`):

```
# Lazy load NVM/NPM/Node
lazynvm() {
  unset -f nvm node npm
  export NVM_DIR=/home/<your-user>/.nvm
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
}

nvm() {
  lazynvm
  nvm $@
}

node() {
  lazynvm
  node $@
}

npm() {
  lazynvm
  npm $@
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be by making `PATH` variable to include your `/bin` location of your `NVM_DIR`. Here is the example:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Add this line to make PATH variable contains your binary of Node from NVM

```
export PATH="$NVM_DIR/versions/node/$(nvm version)/bin:$PATH"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

Install nvm globally with
`wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.32.1/install.sh | sudo bash`

Comment: creationix authors nvm, i'd be very careful about this third-party nvm...

Comment: This branch is 12 commits ahead, 1123 commits behind creationix:master. This is a problem, please remove the link

Comment: This answer makes my eyes bleed. You just **shouldn't** download anything and run it in a sudo bash, wtf

Comment: Actually, the wget command these days ends in `| bash`, no sudo anywhere: [nvm-sh/nvm: Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update)