# How to install older version of nodejs via n?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've newly set up an environment, and installed nodejs from github, 0.11.14-pre. npm as well, 1.4.9. So, the problem is that my entire code base is on node@0.6.9. Upgrade isn't my option because it's too much work for it. I tried `sudo n 0.6.9`. It gives me `Error : invalid version 0.6.9`. Also I tried `sudo n 0.10.28`, and worked perfectly.

Is there any way to install node@0.6.9 manually or via n?

**EDIT**
nvm worked great for me, though it took me hours to install and run nvm. Also - I had a problem to have nvm install nodejs as a normal user due to a permission denial of creating a folder. But nvm-global solved my problems and was easy to install.
https://github.com/xtuple/nvm

Comment: nvm-global is a good but not perfect solution: https://github.com/xtuple/nvm. As for `n`, if it doesn't so something that you think it should do, please file an issue here: https://github.com/visionmedia/n/issues **Disclaimer**: I created the xtuple/nvm-global fork, which you reference in your edit, and I also am a maintainer of n. I'll gladly review any issues you'd like to submit to either of those projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this yet.. but this Node Version Manager looks really promising
[Github: Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

Comment: I could somehow install v0.6.9 via nvm but I had to install nvm manually, not by an install script. Also - I have a same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215059/cant-use-nvm-from-root-or-sudo But this is another story, so thanks anyway.