# How can I use NVM as sudoer?

Tags: linux, npm, sudo, sudoers

How can I use NVM (Node Version Manager) as a sudoer?

What is the sudoer syntax for the /etc/sudoers file (debian wheezy) using NVM from /root/.nvm/ ?

```
username ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/apache2 restart, ... nvm ?
```

The answers from the thread [Can't use NVM from root (or sudo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215059/cant-use-nvm-from-root-or-sudo) did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

i first used the package from https://github.com/creatonix/nvm .
after installing the older package https://github.com/xtuple/nvm it is possible to use nvm as sudoer.