# require('os').homedir() error on linux

Tags: node.js, sudo

when i execute this single line script in linux as sudo i get an error, on my mac osx i don't.

```
var homedir =require('os').homedir();
```

error:

```
testhomedir.js:1
quire, module, __filename, __dirname) { var homedir = require('os').homedir();
                                                                    ^

TypeError: undefined is not a function

    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/marco/test/testhomedir.js:1:91)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

any idea's?

Comment: You're probably running an old version of Node on Linux (check with `node --version`).

Comment: I'm using version 4.4.7

Comment: I'm running the same version on Linux, works fine. Are you sure that `sudo` is using the correct Node interpreter? Does `sudo node --version` give a different version?

Comment: your right, sudo node --version gives me v0.12.4, i'm using nvm, thats probably why this happens. I found another stackoverflow post with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

As Robert pointed out in the comment my sudo used another version of node than my regular user.

this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215059/cant-use-nvm-from-root-or-sudo) provided me with the answer to my problem

stop all the services that use node and issue the command

```
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

this copies the active used node version to the folder globally used.