# What is the equivalent to "which" for commands that don't refer to executables?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal

I'm trying to find out how a specific command is defined. I've checked all locations of `$PATH` and could not find any file that is named like my command, so it seems to be something else.

Here is an example using nvm, that is not an executable:

```
me@MacBook:~$ which cat
/bin/cat
me@MacBook:~$ which nvm
me@MacBook:~$ nvm --version
0.33.8
```

`which nvm` simply returns nothing.

What is the equivalent of "which" for commands like this in unix based systems?

Comment: Whether it's a script or an executable doesn't matter for `which`. Might be an alias or function though. Try `type nvm`

Comment: It's clearly *not* an executable script located in your PATH -- if it were, `which` would have found it. What you have is instead a function or an alias.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know `which` works with shell/bash files, too. You are right. `nvm` is a function. `type nvm` revealed it.

Comment: (From an application perspective, starting a script with the `+x` bit set and a valid shebang uses the same operating system interface as starting any other executable -- there's literally no difference before the `execv`-family syscall is actually invoked; consequently, there's no difference visible to `which`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's `nvm` and this was just an example. I will change it to be correct tho, because scripts can be found with `which`, too.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/1072112

Comment: @ghoti: yes it is, and the answer given there is better, as it correctly addresses the question of whether `which` should be used at all.

Comment: @nlu yet I haven't found it, because the problem is different, since this is about revealing the definition of a command instead of simply validating the command (executable in their case) exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `type`.

`type nvm` will show how the shell will interpret the command, so unlike `which` it'll show aliases, functions and unexported paths too.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/677212#677212) is an answer to a simiar question that advises against the use of `which` for reasons unrelated to the point in question.

That said, your assumption that `which` can only see executables is wrong.

It does not, however, see functions and aliases by default.

That's why the manpage of which says:

> The recommended way to use this utility is by adding an alias (C shell) or shell function (Bourne
>          shell) for which like the following:

```
   [ba]sh:
        which () {
          (alias; declare -f) | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-functions --show-tilde --show-dot $@
        }
        export -f which
```

If you define this function in your `.bashrc` and re-source it, you should be able to do

```
which -a
```

and it should give you functions and aliases as well.

However, watch out, if maybe some profile or bashrc already defined something for `which`, that takes precedence (you could find that out, with `type -a which` btw).

If I define a script, a function and an alias, called `something` I get with `type -a`:

```
type -a something
something is aliased to `echo "something"'
something is a function
something () 
{ 
    echo "function something"
}    
something is /home/myself/bin/something
```

While `which -a` after creating the function gives me:

```
which -a something
alias something='echo "something"'
   /usr/bin/echo
   /bin/echo
something ()
{ 
    echo "function something"
}
~/bin/something
```