# sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set after chmod 755

Tags: unix, centos

What i tried is this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29903645/4983983

I executed this:

```
n=$(which node); \
n=${n%/bin/node}; \
chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; \
sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

but now i can not execute for example `sudo su` command, i get following error:

> ```
> sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
> ```

I am not sure how can i redo it ?

**EDIT:**
Regarding @Bodo answer:

```
sudo rpm --setperms mkdir
sudo rpm --setugids mkdir
cd /opt
 mkdir test13121
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test13121’: Permission denied
```

`BUT:`

```
sudo  chown root:root /usr/bin/mkdir && sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/mkdir
mkdir test912121
```

Comment: Reinstall your machine.

Comment: I would like to do it another way :/ And what excatly happened?

Comment: `n` probably ended up empty which means you changed the permissions of all files in `/bin/`.

Comment: @tkausl /usr/bin/which: no node in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/username/.local/bin:/home/username/bin)

Comment: and
n=${n%/bin/node};

gives nothing

Comment: @tkausl which of this two operation should return something to run this command safely ?

Comment: As I expected. `which node` is the line which should return the path to the node executable if it is installed.

Comment: @tkausl I started fixing it with this command from root user:  `chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo`  but i am not sure do i have to change every file to 4755 there(in /usr/bin) ? Will this be enough to fix this issue?

Comment: Yeah, why not make every executable setuid root? :D

Comment: @PSkocik i am not sure if this is a joke or not? If not do you mean the same command as i do?

Comment: @tryingHard `/usr/bin/*` executables are typiclally root owned. settting the setuid bit would open huge security holes. `chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo && chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo` should do it, but you need a root shell to be able to execute it.

Comment: It is normal for `cd /opt && mkdir test13121` to fail because `mkdir` is NOT suid-root. You would have to run it as `root`, e.g. with `sudo`. IMHO `rpm --setugids package_name` requires a package name, not a binary. I don't know if there is a package named `mkdir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty is to find out the normal permissions of the files you have changed.

You can try to reset the file permissions based on the information in the package management.

See e.g. https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reset-rhel-centos-fedora-package-file-permission.html

Citation from this page:

> **Reset the permissions of the all installed RPM packages**
>
> You need to use combination of rpm and a shell for loop command as follows:
>
> ```
> for p in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setperms $p; done
> for p in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setugids $p; done
> ```

I suggest to read the linked page completely and try this for a single package first.
I guess you can somehow ask `rpm` to find the package name that contains e.g. `/usr/bin/sudo`. and try if the commands work for a single package.

**Edit:** If the `setuid` or `setgid` bits are not correct, you can try to change the order of the commands and use `--setugids` before `--setperms`. (In some cases `chown` resets `setuid` or `setgid` bits; don't know if this applies to the `rpm` commands.)

There are sources in the internet that propose to combine `--setugids` and`--setperms` in one command or to use option `-a` instead of a loop like

```
rpm -a --setperms
```

Read the documentation. (I don't have an RPM based system where I could test the commands.)

Comment: I have updated question - why is the differnce here ?

Comment: It does not work well with for example `chage` it is now `-rwxr-xr-x.` but was `-rwsr-xr-x.`  the `s` is the difference.

Comment: @tryingHard I don't have an RPM based system for testing. Please read my edit and read the documentation or search for information about "setugids" and "setperms" in the internet.